# Split sentence with many words in to two approximately equal by length pieces

Tags: google-sheets

I have sentences with length between 50-70 symbols in my google spreadsheet. I have to split them into two approximately equal pieces by whitespace.

for example:

"This is sentence with 5 words."

I want to get this:
"This is sentence", "with 5 words."

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the formula to do this:

`=SPLIT(JOIN("",
ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1," "))&
if(MOD(row(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(SPLIT(A1," ")))),3)=0,CHAR(10)," "))),CHAR(10))`

change this:

- `A1` to cell that contains text, change it 2 times
- `3` to number of words in pieces

For example, this text in cell A1:
`one to 3 for 5 six 7 eit nine ten` will be converted into pieces:

`one to 3`

`for 5 six`

`7 eit nine`

`ten`

note that last piece contains only one word, it's the rest after all words were splited.

---

**Edit**

The key tho this formula is number of words, counted in it:
`=COUNTA(SPLIT(A1," "))`

To get approximate number of words in each part, use this formula:

`=CEILING(COUNTA(SPLIT(A1," "))/2)`

And the total formula will be:

```
=SPLIT(JOIN("", ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1," "))& if(MOD(row(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(SPLIT(A1," ")))),CEILING(COUNTA(SPLIT(A1," "))/2))=0,CHAR(10)," "))),CHAR(10))
```

This formula doesn't count number of letters in sentence, so it can give not equal parts.

---

**Also try**

This formulas count number of lettets and will split the text accordingly. It might work better for big sentences.

Formula for part1, paste in B1:

```
=TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REPT("[^ ]+ ",counta(SPLIT(LEFT(A1,CEILING(LEN(A1)/2))," ")))))
```

Formula for part2, paste in C1:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,""))
```

Comment: Thanks. It should split exactly into two pisces. And if it possible (by length) each piece should be less then base string length/2.

Comment: @Alex T. I find this question is quite old. But still need to get your response. DId this answer match your needs?

Answer (score 0):

To change "This is sentence with 5 words." to "This is sentence", "with 5 words." try:

```
=join(""", """,(SPLIT(JOIN("", ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1," "))& if(MOD(row(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(SPLIT(A1," ")))),CEILING(COUNTA(SPLIT(A1," "))/2))=0,CHAR(10)," "))),CHAR(10))))
```